# How to keep a form responsive whilst a Do Loop statement is running

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms

If you run the following code you will see that you can not click `Button2` whilst the `Do[...]Loop` statement is running:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = True
        Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
        wb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")


        Dim wsSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
        wsSheet1 = CType(wb1.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

        Do
            wsSheet1.Cells.Copy()
            wsSheet1.Cells.PasteSpecial(Paste:=Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues)
        Loop

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MsgBox("Hello")
    End Sub

End Class
```

How do you keep `Form1` responsive whilst the `Do[...]Loop` statement is running?

Comment: If you want your UI responsive during long-running tasks then you must use a secondary thread.  That can be done in various ways, including using the `Task` class.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't a coding service. You need to make an attempt yourself and then someone would be able to assist you with issues if you have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep your form responsive whilst the `Do[...]Loop` statement is running you need to run it on a separate thread using the [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

First create a new method and place the `Do[...]Loop` statement in that method:

```
Private Sub CopyCells(ByVal worksheet As Excel.Worksheet)

    Do
        worksheet.Cells.Copy()
        worksheet.Cells.PasteSpecial(Paste:=Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues)
    Loop

End Sub
```

You can then call this method using [Task.Factory.StartNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() CopyCells(wsSheet1))
```

I would also move away from using `MsgBox` and use `MessageBox.Show`. `MsgBox` exists for VB6 and ends up delegating to `MessageBox` anyway so makes sense to use `MessageBox.Show`:

```
MessageBox.Show("Hello")
```

In full your code would look something similar to this:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
        xlApp.Visible = True

        Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
        wb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Book1.xlsx")

        Dim wsSheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
        wsSheet1 = CType(wb1.Sheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() CopyCells(wsSheet1))

    End Sub

    Private Sub CopyCells(ByVal worksheet As Excel.Worksheet)

        Do
            worksheet.Cells.Copy()
            worksheet.Cells.PasteSpecial(Paste:=Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteValues)
        Loop

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    End Sub

End Class
```

> Note that you will have to import `System.Threading.Tasks` to make use of the `Task` class.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read, it sounds like your UI is becoming unresponsive when you are asking your program to do a particular task
In this case you should look into the `Background Worker`examples on msdn or you could use another thread without using the Background Worker, it really your choice.
 Here is a quick example I have written up that will draw rectangle boxes to the screen in a random position using a different thread, this will allow you to move the window around while it draws to the screen and to interact with other components and have them work correctly without it freezing such as a `MessageBox`.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Form1
Dim random0 As New Random
Dim thread0 As New Threading.Thread(New Threading.ThreadStart(AddressOf threadDrawing0))

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    thread0.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
    thread0.Abort()
End Sub

Private Sub threadDrawing0()
    For i = 0 To 1000
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Me.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(New Pen(Brushes.Blue, 4), New Rectangle(random0.Next(0, Me.Width), random0.Next(0, Me.Height), 20, 20))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MessageBox.Show("Hello World")
End Sub
End Class
```

Because I dont have the excel file you are working with, I am unable to test the code to your exact needs, however this should well and truly get you on the right path.
 MSDN Background Worker Link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx