# Generating all possible combinations the fastest way

Tags: vb.net

I have to generate a list of combinations with a range of numbers `[0, 1, ..., 9]` with a length of 6 digits.

I need 1 million of combinations and it takes a lot of time to do it.

I tried using 2 threads to see if it would go faster, but I get an `exception`.

code:

```
Try
        'again:
        For i = 0 To 9
            For c = 0 To 9
                For d = 0 To 9
                    For b = 0 To 9
                        For a = 0 To 9
                            For f = 0 To 9
                                If ListBox2.Items.Contains(i & c & d & b & a & f) Then
                                    Continue For
                                Else
                                    ListBox2.Items.Add(i & c & d & b & a & f)
                                    Label2.Text = ListBox2.Items.Count
                                End If
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
Catch ex As Exception
    'GoTo again
End Try
```

Now, if I run it with **1 thread**, it goes **OK** but it takes a lot of time.

If I try with **2 threads** it goes faster, but at some point it raises an exception at `If ListBox2.Items.Contains(...) then`

Exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I think because the 2 threads get caught trying to check the `listbox2` at the same time, this happens?

Comment: You cannnot access UI objects on a different thread than the UI thread.  A UI control seems a bad storage chpice to begin with for 3.6 million items, and it can be done more simply than that with linq.  Gobs of really good answers here on permutation and combinations.  That code also looks like you should turn on Option Strict

Comment: this should speed it up, first create a public list string `Dim Combination As New List(Of String)` and then run this where you want the code to execute from.`For i As Integer = 0 To 999999
            Combination.Add(String.Format("{0:D6}", i))
        Next`
This WILL lock up your application, so I suggest you take a look at `Background Workers` or read up on using more than one thread, I have an answer on my profile that you might find helpful. good luck
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246886/how-to-keep-a-form-responsive-whilst-a-do-loop-statement-is-running/43248582#43248582

Comment: @Werdna I tried it now and it's fastest for sure! And using this way i can use multiple threads! i didn't know i could use `string.format` this way!

Comment: @Plutonix Yes, i used `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False` but i know its not a good practice! I think @Werdna comment works for me.

Comment: Thats a bad practice... I wanna poke my eyes out.

Comment: @Zaggler Yes, I'm learning about `delegates` now, but I'm not very good at it.

Comment: How did you go? did you still need help?

Comment: @Werdna I accepted the answer from dbasnett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to produce 900,000 combinations, which runs in under a second.

```
Private Function Combinations() As List(Of String)
    Static prng As New Random
    Dim a() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Function(n) n * 1).OrderBy(Function(y) prng.Next()).ToArray
    Dim b() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Function(n) n * 10).OrderBy(Function(y) prng.Next()).ToArray
    Dim c() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Function(n) n * 100).OrderBy(Function(y) prng.Next()).ToArray
    Dim d() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Function(n) n * 1000).OrderBy(Function(y) prng.Next()).ToArray
    Dim e() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(Function(n) n * 10000).OrderBy(Function(y) prng.Next()).ToArray
    Dim f() As Integer = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).Select(Function(n) n * 100000).OrderBy(Function(y) prng.Next()).ToArray

    Dim rv As New List(Of String)
    Dim ts As New List(Of Task(Of List(Of String)))

    For Each a1 As Integer In a
        Dim t As Task(Of List(Of String)) = Task.Run(Function()
                                                         Dim i As New List(Of Integer)
                                                         For Each b1 As Integer In b
                                                             For Each c1 As Integer In c
                                                                 For Each d1 As Integer In d
                                                                     For Each e1 As Integer In e
                                                                         For Each f1 As Integer In f
                                                                             Dim x As Integer = a1 + b1 + c1 + d1 + e1 + f1
                                                                             i.Add(x)
                                                                         Next
                                                                     Next
                                                                 Next
                                                             Next
                                                         Next
                                                         Return i.Select(Function(s) s.ToString()).ToList
                                                     End Function)
        ts.Add(t)
    Next

    Task.WaitAll(ts.ToArray)
    For Each t As Task(Of List(Of String)) In ts
        rv.AddRange(t.Result)
    Next
    Return rv
End Function
```

The adding to a listbox takes quite a bit longer

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ListBox1.BeginUpdate()
    ListBox1.DataSource = Combinations()
    ListBox1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you pushing linq and then u are doing for each...and at sake you have nested fors... how about all linq?

Comment: @dbasnett that is actually very fast, a bit more advanced, but its definitely the fastest way

Comment: @Zaggler - how about it?

Answer (score 1):

There are some very good libraries for combinatorics. It is not needed to reinvent the wheel, just use them.

[Combinatorics Library for Microsoft .NET](https://github.com/eoincampbell/combinatorics)

[KwCombinatorics: K-Combination, Permutation, Cartesian Product classes in C#](http://kwcombinatorics.codeplex.com/)

If you think you are good enough, you can use [Alea GPU](http://www.quantalea.com/) or [CUDAfy.NET](https://cudafy.codeplex.com/) to compute everything directly on GPU, which will be thousands times faster than on CPU.

Comment: I know that there are library's that do the job better but i wanted to do it without them, sorry if i didn't specify on the question. Either way your answer is very helpful and im gonna look into it, thank you!